# How using the tag <select> change code in <div>?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two "option" in "select".

```
<select>
    <option>textarea</option>
    <option>text</option>
</select>
<div>

</div>
```

I need when choosing `"option-text"` showed `"input type=text"` in tag `"div"`, and when choosing `"option-textarea"` showed `"textarea"`.

Using javascript or jQuery.

Comment: [`Document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should do the trick.

```js
function addElement (elem) { 
  var selectBox = document.getElementById("selectBox");
    var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;

  // create a new div element 
  var newElem = document.createElement(selectedValue); 

  // add the newly created element and its content into the DOM 
  var currentDiv = document.getElementById("content"); 
  currentDiv.innerHTML = newElem.outerHTML;
}
```

```html
<select id="selectBox" onchange="addElement();">
        <option value='textarea'>textarea</option>
        <option value='input'>text</option>
    </select>
    <div id='content'>

    </div>
```

There might be a better way but this is the first thing that came to my mind. Basically, using ID's and the onchange event you can make a simple function that does what you need. You should learn DOM manipulation with javascript if you want to understand the concept better.